# pandas dataframe: convert 2 columns (value, value) into 2 columns (value, type)

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have the following dataframe **"A"**

```
         utilization  utilization_billable
service                                   
1               10.0                   5.0
2               30.0                  20.0
3               40.0                  30.0
4               40.0                  32.0
```

I need to convert it into the following dataframe **"B"**

```
         utilization      type
service                       
1               10.0     total
2               30.0     total
3               40.0     total
4               40.0     total
1                5.0  billable
2               20.0  billable
3               30.0  billable
4               32.0  billable
```

so the values from the first are categorized into **type** column with values of total or billable.

```
data = {
    'utilization': [10.0, 30.0, 40.0, 40.0],
    'utilization_billable': [5.0, 20.0, 30.0, 32.0],
    'service': [1, 2, 3, 4]
}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data).set_index('service')
print(df)

data = {
    'utilization': [10.0, 30.0, 40.0, 40.0, 5.0, 20.0, 30.0, 32.0],
    'service': [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4],
    'type': [
        'total',
        'total',
        'total',
        'total',
        'billable',
        'billable',
        'billable',
        'billable',
    ]
}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data).set_index('service')
print(df)
```

#### Is there a way to transform the data frame and perform such categorization?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [`pd.melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.melt.html):

```
import pandas as pd
data = {
    'utilization': [10.0, 30.0, 40.0, 40.0],
    'utilization_billable': [5.0, 20.0, 30.0, 32.0],
    'service': [1, 2, 3, 4]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
result =  pd.melt(df, var_name='type', value_name='utilization', id_vars='service')
print(result)
```

yields

```
   service                  type  utilization
0        1           utilization         10.0
1        2           utilization         30.0
2        3           utilization         40.0
3        4           utilization         40.0
4        1  utilization_billable          5.0
5        2  utilization_billable         20.0
6        3  utilization_billable         30.0
7        4  utilization_billable         32.0
```

Then `result.set_index('service')` would make `service` the index,
but I would recommend avoiding that since `service` values are not unique.

Comment: Another syntax for `melt`.  use `pd.DataFrame.melt` instead of `pd.melt` like this:  `df.reset_index().melt('service', var_name='type').set_index('service')`

Answer (score 2):

looks like a job for `df.stack()` with multiple `DataFrame.rename()`

```
df.rename(index=str, columns={"utilization": "total", "utilization_billable": "billable"})\
  .stack().reset_index(1).rename(index=str, columns={"level_1": "type", 0: "utilization"})\
  .sort_values(by='type', ascending = False)
```

Output:

```
             type  utilization
service                       
1           total         10.0
2           total         30.0
3           total         40.0
4           total         40.0
1        billable          5.0
2        billable         20.0
3        billable         30.0
4        billable         32.0
```

Answer (score 2):

This can be done with `pd.wide_to_long` after adding a suffix to the first column.

```
import pandas as pd
df = df.rename(columns={'utilization': 'utilization_total'})

pd.wide_to_long(df.reset_index(), stubnames='utilization', sep='_', 
                i='service', j='type', suffix='.*').reset_index(1)
```

#### Output:

```
             type  utilization
service                       
1           total         10.0
2           total         30.0
3           total         40.0
4           total         40.0
1        billable          5.0
2        billable         20.0
3        billable         30.0
4        billable         32.0
```